# Rails Active Storage "attach" ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I am using Rails Active Storage and I am trying to attach an MP3 file to an object, but I am getting the following error:

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)):
```

Here is the code I currently have:

```
def perform(streamplay)
    text = File.open(streamplay.text_path).read
    text = perform_regex(text)
    convert = convert_to_audio(text)
    audio = convert.audio_content
    filename = streamplay.screenplay.title

    # The response's audio_content is binary.
    File.open "/output.mp3", "wb" do |file|
      # Write the response to the output file.
      file.write audio
    end
    streamplay.file.attach(
      io: File.open("#{Rails.root}/output.mp3"),
      filename: "#{filename}.mp3",
      content_type: "audio/mpeg",
      identify: false
    )
  end
```

I can see that the audio file is getting written to the root directory, and I can listen to it on my computer, so the file is coming through. It's at this bit of the code that things seem to be breaking down:

```
streamplay.file.attach
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it looks like the issue was actually in the `File.open` section here:

```
File.open "/output.mp3", "wb" do |file|
      # Write the response to the output file.
      file.write audio
    end
```

I had to remove the preceding "/" before "output.mp3". So instead I now have this and it works:

```
File.open "output.mp3", "wb" do |file|
      # Write the response to the output file.
      file.write audio
    end
```